# Vue/HTML5/Safari - Video can't show on safari but Chrome

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, vue.js, safari

I'm using Django + Vue.js to build a showcase website.
All my video is working perfect on chrome. But safari and iPhone just not working.
Server respond **status 499**?

I used to use video from other domain and it works(I copy the video link which is depoloy on facebook cdn.) But it got url expired issue. so I download the video and use it.
However that was the nightmare started.

[Video failed to load on safari. said Byte0-1?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJJ9P.png)

I have static video on my server.
html:

```
<div id="filters" class='filters row'>
    <section class='filter col s6 m4 l3'
        v-for="filter in filters_data"
    >
        <video muted='true' loop='true' autoplay>
            <source class="demo" v-if='filter.demo_replace == null' :src="filter.demo">
            <source v-else class="replace_demo" :src="filter.demo_replace">
        </video>
        <a :href="filter.link">
            <div class='filter-info'>
                <img class='avatar' :src="filter.avatar" alt="">
                <h3>[[filter.name]]</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </section>
</div>
```

rendered html

```
<section class="filter col s6 m4 l3">
   <video muted="muted" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay">
      <source src="/media/Poop Hat.mp4" class="demo">
   </video>
   <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ar/3339649326099588">
      <div class="filter-info">
         <img src="https://scontent.fkhh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.10260-6/105918489_590471668536013_898732822726448347_n.png?_nc_cat=102&amp;_nc_sid=df6b83&amp;_nc_ohc=XB8y_mkhow8AX-Q_FyZ&amp;_nc_ht=scontent.fkhh1-1.fna&amp;oh=c6f78dab6ac3cc59f4c2bd7f522250f1&amp;oe=5F26E3D0" alt="" class="avatar"> 
         <h3>Poop Hat</h3>
      </div>
   </a>
</section>
```

vue.js:

```
var app = new Vue({
delimiters:['[[', ']]'],
el: '#filters',
http: {
  root: './root', 
  headers: {
    'Content-Range': 'bytes=0-3549043', 
    'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
    'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
  }
},
data: {
    'message':'hello',
    'filters_data': []
},
mounted () {
  axios
    .get('filters/api/filters/')
    .then(response => {
        let data = response.data
        for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        data[i].demo = "/media/" + data[i].name + ".mp4"
        data[i].link = "https://www.instagram.com/ar/"+data[i].link.split('/')[6] 
            this.filters_data.push(data[i]);
        }
        
    })
    .catch(function (error) { // 请求失败处理
      console.log(error);
    });
}});
```

if there is others I can provide. let me know.

Comment: Just to go for the low hanging fruit, and it is iphone/safari we are talking about. Could you just try renaming your file `/media/Poop Hat.mp4` to `/media/poop_hat.mp4`, because spaces and html encoding and stuff does not always work perfectly in all browsers.

Comment: @ippi thanks for your quick reply and all the help. I'll fix this. However this is not the main problem. cuz i got plenty videos and some of them not include spacing. and those vid not showing neither.